# Is Astral Construct incomplete?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, monsters, psionics

The *astral construct* psionic power states: For every 2 additional power points you spend, the level of the astral construct increases by one.

But, the monster entry only lists up to level 9 (for 17 pp) astral constructs. Why does it stop here?

Other than the lack of a printed 10th+ level astral construct, what prevents me from paying 19 pp for a level 10 construct?

What would it look like?

Comment: D&D3.5's psionics system was designed to have a lot of the same mechanics as the spellcasting system. 17 pp = 9th level spell, which is where the normal system "caps out."

Comment: The 3.5 psionics system doesn't have the same caps that arcane/divine magic does, however. The only instances in which actual caps are in place are arcane spells turned psionic powers (ex. dispel psionics has a +20 cap). In the instance of Astral Construct, there's not so much a cap as there is a lack of constructs above 9th level printed in the book.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to be correct: there is no limitation of 17 Power Points or 9th-level Astral Constructs on the *astral construct* power, but the Astral Construct creature entry does not describe what happens when you spend 19 or more Power Points on the power. Numerous forum questions out there exist about this subject (and worse, what happens with Epic shapers).

There was apparently a “Menu D” available at one point, though I’ve seen a few people state it has been “lost,” whatever that means. A search for Astral Construct Menu D found [this Mind’s Eye article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190913143851/http://archive.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=dnd/pse/20020727c) which has a Menu D, but I think it is for the 3.0 *Psionics Handbook*, not the 3.5 *Expanded Psionics Handbook*. Still, might be maybe a bit useful.

Several people also suggest the book *Untapped Potential* by Dreamscarred Press for its *astral juggernaut* 9th-level power. It seems reasonable to me to say something like: “Augment: if you spend 19 power points on *astral construct*, it functions instead as *astral juggernaut*” if you wanted.